# IF Reference cell is blank

Tags: excel, if-statement, logic

Hello these are two formulas that i have and work perfectly when it has values in the reference cells. I do not know how to show zero if the reference key is Blank.

Please help

```
=IF(AND(E10=E3,G10=G3),3,0)
```

and

```
=IF(OR(AND(E3>G3,E10>G10)),1,0)+IF(OR(AND(E3=G3,E10=G10)),1,0)+IF(OR(AND(E3<G3,E10<G10)),1,0)
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use isempty function
or(isempty(E10),isempty(E3),isempty(G10),isempty(G3) will return true if on of the reference key is blank

if(or(isempty(E10),isempty(E3),isempty(G10),isempty(G3)),0,IF(AND(E10=E3,G10=G3),3,0))